# Организация системы управления MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица `event` со следующей структурой
id
user_id
text
created_at(timestamp)

Нужен запрос, который вытаскивает все записи добавленные более 30 минут назад, получает `user_id` и вытаскивает все записи с этим `user_id` за последние 30 мин.

Задача изначально такая: необходимо создать систему уведомлений. Соответственно отсылать уведомления нужно пачками(несколько штук), от одного пользователя "пачка" должна приходить не чаще чем раз в 30 мин.

Пользователь совершает какие-то правки в своем профиле, а потом все эти правки группируются и отправляются админу( раз в 30 минут), чтобы не засорять правки по каждому юзеру группируются и отправляются пакетами.

Например

|id|user_id|------|created_at

-1----5----------минуту назад

-2----5----------5 мин назад

Для такой таблицы мы ничего не вытаскиваем
а для:

|id|user_id|------|created_at

-1----5----------31 мин назад

-2----5----------5 мин назад

Мы вытаскиваем все 2 записи

Comment: Сами то пробовали реализовать

Comment: В 1 запрос не получается

Comment: Если не сложно переформулируйте пожалуйста фразу "Нужен запрос, который вытаскивает все записи добавленные более 30 минут назад, получает user_id и вытаскивает все записи с этим user_id за последние 30 мин." - нужны уведомления за последние 30 минут? Пока не понятно зачем предварительно извлекать user_id пользователей, почему бы просто не извлечь сообщения за последние 30 минут.

Comment: В том то и дело что нет. Уведомления за последние 30 минут нужны в   случае, если существует уведомление добавленное более 30 мин назад.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от того, какой процент пользователей подпадает под условие можно сделать разными способами.

Если пользователей у которых были события за последние 30 минут много (кажем более 25% от всех пользователей системы), то подойдет такой запрос:

```
select *
  from event
 where user_id in(
        select user_id
          from event
         where created_at < now() - interval 30 minute
       )
   and created_at >= now() - interval 30 minute
```

Если же пользователей мало, то по быстродействию возможно будет более выгоден такой запрос:

```
select *
  from event E
 where created_at >= now() - interval 30 minute
   and exists(select 1 from event E1
               where E1.created_at < now() - interval 30 minute
                 and E1.user_id=E.user_id
             )
```